# Ruby: Should strings in a frozen array also be individually frozen?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, string

Ruby 2.2.3, Rails 4.2.1

I have a large number of arrays of strings that I define as constants for use throughout an application. They are various sets of ISO country codes, language codes, that sort of thing, so two to four characters, numbered in the hundreds of unique values each.

The different arrays are collections of these, so NORTH_AMERICA_COUNTRY_CODES might be an array of a dozen of so country codes, AFRICA_COUNTRY_CODES might be an array of around 60. Many of them overlap (various versions of the Commonwealth countries,  for example).

The arrays are used in comparison with other arbitrary arrays of country codes for logic such as "Subtract this list of countries from Africa".

So I'm wondering whether, when I generate these constants, I ought to freeze the strings within the arrays, so instead of:

```
WORLD_COUNTRIES = Countries.pluck(:country_code).freeze
```

... maybe ...

```
WORLD_COUNTRIES = Countries.pluck(:country_code).map{|c| c.freeze}.freeze
```

Is there a way of quantifying the potential benefits?

I considered using arrays of symbols instead of arrays of strings, but the arbitrary arrays that these are used with are stored in PostgreSQL text arrays, and it seems like I'd need to serialise those columns instead, or maybe override the getter and setter methods to change the values between arrays of strings and arrays of symbols. Ugh.

## Edit

Testing results, in which I've attempted to benchmark three situations:

1. Comparing a frozen array of unfrozen strings with an unfrozen array of unfrozen strings
2. Comparing a frozen array of *frozen* strings with an unfrozen array of unfrozen strings
3. Comparing a frozen array of symbols with an unfrozen array of symbols (in case I bit the bullet and went all symbolic on this).

Any thoughts on methodology or interpretation gratefully received. I'm not sure whether the similarity in results between the first two indicates that they are in all respects the same, but I'd be keen on anything that can directly point to differences in memory allocation.

Script:

```
require 'benchmark'

country_list             = ["AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AI", "AL", "AM", "AN", "AO", "AQ", "AR", "AS", "AT", "AU", "AW", "AX", "AZ", "BA", "BB", "BD", "BE", "BF", "BG", "BH", "BI", "BJ", "BL", "BM", "BN", "BO", "BQ", "BR", "BS", "BT", "BV", "BW", "BY", "BZ", "CA", "CC", "CD", "CF", "CG", "CH", "CI", "CK", "CL", "CM", "CN", "CO", "CR", "CS", "CU", "CV", "CW", "CX", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DJ", "DK", "DM", "DO", "DZ", "EC", "EE", "EG", "EH", "ER", "ES", "ET", "FI", "FJ", "FK", "FM", "FO", "FR", "GA", "GB", "GD", "GE", "GF", "GG", "GH", "GI", "GL", "GM", "GN", "GP", "GQ", "GR", "GS", "GT", "GU", "GW", "GY", "HK", "HM", "HN", "HR", "HT", "HU", "ID", "IE", "IL", "IM", "IN", "IO", "IQ", "IR", "IS", "IT", "JE", "JM", "JO", "JP", "KE", "KG", "KH", "KI", "KM", "KN", "KP", "KR", "KW", "KY", "KZ", "LA", "LB", "LC", "LI", "LK", "LR", "LS", "LT", "LU", "LV", "LY", "MA", "MC", "MD", "ME", "MF", "MG", "MH", "MK", "ML", "MM", "MN", "MO", "MP", "MQ", "MR", "MS", "MT", "MU", "MV", "MW", "MX", "MY", "MZ", "NA", "NC", "NE", "NF", "NG", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NP", "NR", "NU", "NZ", "OM", "PA", "PE", "PF", "PG", "PH", "PK", "PL", "PM", "PN", "PR", "PS", "PT", "PW", "PY", "QA", "RE", "RO", "RS", "RU", "RW", "SA", "SB", "SC", "SD", "SE", "SG", "SH", "SI", "SJ", "SK", "SL", "SM", "SN", "SO", "SR", "SS", "ST", "SV", "SX", "SY", "SZ", "TC", "TD", "TF", "TG", "TH", "TJ", "TK", "TL", "TM", "TN", "TO", "TR", "TT", "TV", "TW", "TZ", "UA", "UG", "UM", "US", "UY", "UZ", "VA", "VC", "VE", "VG", "VI", "VN", "VU", "WF", "WS", "YE", "YT", "YU", "ZA", "ZM", "ZW"] 
FROZEN_ARRAY             = country_list.dup.freeze
puts FROZEN_ARRAY.size
FROZEN_ARRAY_AND_STRINGS = country_list.dup.map{|x| x.freeze}.freeze
FROZEN_ARRAY_AND_SYMBOLS = country_list.dup.map{|x| x.to_sym}.freeze
comp_s                   = %w(AD AT BE CY EE FI FR DE ES GR IE IT LU LV MC ME MT NL PT SI SK SM VA)
comp_sym                 = %w(AD AT BE CY EE FI FR DE ES GR IE IT LU LV MC ME MT NL PT SI SK SM VA).map{|x| x.to_sym}


Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("frozen string"  )  { 10000.times {|i| c = (FROZEN_ARRAY_AND_STRINGS & comp_s.dup) }}
  x.report("unfrozen string")  { 10000.times {|i| c = (FROZEN_ARRAY             & comp_s.dup) }}
  x.report("symbols"        )  { 10000.times {|i| c = (FROZEN_ARRAY_AND_SYMBOLS & comp_sym.dup) }}
end


Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report("frozen string"  )  { 10000.times {|i| c = (FROZEN_ARRAY_AND_STRINGS & comp_s.dup) }}
  x.report("unfrozen string")  { 10000.times {|i| c = (FROZEN_ARRAY             & comp_s.dup) }}
  x.report("symbols"        )  { 10000.times {|i| c = (FROZEN_ARRAY_AND_SYMBOLS & comp_sym.dup) }}
end
```

Result:

```
2.2.3 :001 > require 'benchmark'
 => false 
2.2.3 :002 > 
2.2.3 :003 >   country_list             = ["AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AI", "AL", "AM", "AN", "AO", "AQ", "AR", "AS", "AT", "AU", "AW", "AX", "AZ", "BA", "BB", "BD", "BE", "BF", "BG", "BH", "BI", "BJ", "BL", "BM", "BN", "BO", "BQ", "BR", "BS", "BT", "BV", "BW", "BY", "BZ", "CA", "CC", "CD", "CF", "CG", "CH", "CI", "CK", "CL", "CM", "CN", "CO", "CR", "CS", "CU", "CV", "CW", "CX", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DJ", "DK", "DM", "DO", "DZ", "EC", "EE", "EG", "EH", "ER", "ES", "ET", "FI", "FJ", "FK", "FM", "FO", "FR", "GA", "GB", "GD", "GE", "GF", "GG", "GH", "GI", "GL", "GM", "GN", "GP", "GQ", "GR", "GS", "GT", "GU", "GW", "GY", "HK", "HM", "HN", "HR", "HT", "HU", "ID", "IE", "IL", "IM", "IN", "IO", "IQ", "IR", "IS", "IT", "JE", "JM", "JO", "JP", "KE", "KG", "KH", "KI", "KM", "KN", "KP", "KR", "KW", "KY", "KZ", "LA", "LB", "LC", "LI", "LK", "LR", "LS", "LT", "LU", "LV", "LY", "MA", "MC", "MD", "ME", "MF", "MG", "MH", "MK", "ML", "MM", "MN", "MO", "MP", "MQ", "MR", "MS", "MT", "MU", "MV", "MW", "MX", "MY", "MZ", "NA", "NC", "NE", "NF", "NG", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NP", "NR", "NU", "NZ", "OM", "PA", "PE", "PF", "PG", "PH", "PK", "PL", "PM", "PN", "PR", "PS", "PT", "PW", "PY", "QA", "RE", "RO", "RS", "RU", "RW", "SA", "SB", "SC", "SD", "SE", "SG", "SH", "SI", "SJ", "SK", "SL", "SM", "SN", "SO", "SR", "SS", "ST", "SV", "SX", "SY", "SZ", "TC", "TD", "TF", "TG", "TH", "TJ", "TK", "TL", "TM", "TN", "TO", "TR", "TT", "TV", "TW", "TZ", "UA", "UG", "UM", "US", "UY", "UZ", "VA", "VC", "VE", "VG", "VI", "VN", "VU", "WF", "WS", "YE", "YT", "YU", "ZA", "ZM", "ZW"] 
 => ["AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AI", "AL", "AM", "AN", "AO", "AQ", "AR", "AS", "AT", "AU", "AW", "AX", "AZ", "BA", "BB", "BD", "BE", "BF", "BG", "BH", "BI", "BJ", "BL", "BM", "BN", "BO", "BQ", "BR", "BS", "BT", "BV", "BW", "BY", "BZ", "CA", "CC", "CD", "CF", "CG", "CH", "CI", "CK", "CL", "CM", "CN", "CO", "CR", "CS", "CU", "CV", "CW", "CX", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DJ", "DK", "DM", "DO", "DZ", "EC", "EE", "EG", "EH", "ER", "ES", "ET", "FI", "FJ", "FK", "FM", "FO", "FR", "GA", "GB", "GD", "GE", "GF", "GG", "GH", "GI", "GL", "GM", "GN", "GP", "GQ", "GR", "GS", "GT", "GU", "GW", "GY", "HK", "HM", "HN", "HR", "HT", "HU", "ID", "IE", "IL", "IM", "IN", "IO", "IQ", "IR", "IS", "IT", "JE", "JM", "JO", "JP", "KE", "KG", "KH", "KI", "KM", "KN", "KP", "KR", "KW", "KY", "KZ", "LA", "LB", "LC", "LI", "LK", "LR", "LS", "LT", "LU", "LV", "LY", "MA", "MC", "MD", "ME", "MF", "MG", "MH", "MK", "ML", "MM", "MN", "MO", "MP", "MQ", "MR", "MS", "MT", "MU", "MV", "MW", "MX", "MY", "MZ", "NA", "NC", "NE", "NF", "NG", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NP", "NR", "NU", "NZ", "OM", "PA", "PE", "PF", "PG", "PH", "PK", "PL", "PM", "PN", "PR", "PS", "PT", "PW", "PY", "QA", "RE", "RO", "RS", "RU", "RW", "SA", "SB", "SC", "SD", "SE", "SG", "SH", "SI", "SJ", "SK", "SL", "SM", "SN", "SO", "SR", "SS", "ST", "SV", "SX", "SY", "SZ", "TC", "TD", "TF", "TG", "TH", "TJ", "TK", "TL", "TM", "TN", "TO", "TR", "TT", "TV", "TW", "TZ", "UA", "UG", "UM", "US", "UY", "UZ", "VA", "VC", "VE", "VG", "VI", "VN", "VU", "WF", "WS", "YE", "YT", "YU", "ZA", "ZM", "ZW"] 
2.2.3 :004 > FROZEN_ARRAY             = country_list.dup.freeze
 => ["AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AI", "AL", "AM", "AN", "AO", "AQ", "AR", "AS", "AT", "AU", "AW", "AX", "AZ", "BA", "BB", "BD", "BE", "BF", "BG", "BH", "BI", "BJ", "BL", "BM", "BN", "BO", "BQ", "BR", "BS", "BT", "BV", "BW", "BY", "BZ", "CA", "CC", "CD", "CF", "CG", "CH", "CI", "CK", "CL", "CM", "CN", "CO", "CR", "CS", "CU", "CV", "CW", "CX", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DJ", "DK", "DM", "DO", "DZ", "EC", "EE", "EG", "EH", "ER", "ES", "ET", "FI", "FJ", "FK", "FM", "FO", "FR", "GA", "GB", "GD", "GE", "GF", "GG", "GH", "GI", "GL", "GM", "GN", "GP", "GQ", "GR", "GS", "GT", "GU", "GW", "GY", "HK", "HM", "HN", "HR", "HT", "HU", "ID", "IE", "IL", "IM", "IN", "IO", "IQ", "IR", "IS", "IT", "JE", "JM", "JO", "JP", "KE", "KG", "KH", "KI", "KM", "KN", "KP", "KR", "KW", "KY", "KZ", "LA", "LB", "LC", "LI", "LK", "LR", "LS", "LT", "LU", "LV", "LY", "MA", "MC", "MD", "ME", "MF", "MG", "MH", "MK", "ML", "MM", "MN", "MO", "MP", "MQ", "MR", "MS", "MT", "MU", "MV", "MW", "MX", "MY", "MZ", "NA", "NC", "NE", "NF", "NG", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NP", "NR", "NU", "NZ", "OM", "PA", "PE", "PF", "PG", "PH", "PK", "PL", "PM", "PN", "PR", "PS", "PT", "PW", "PY", "QA", "RE", "RO", "RS", "RU", "RW", "SA", "SB", "SC", "SD", "SE", "SG", "SH", "SI", "SJ", "SK", "SL", "SM", "SN", "SO", "SR", "SS", "ST", "SV", "SX", "SY", "SZ", "TC", "TD", "TF", "TG", "TH", "TJ", "TK", "TL", "TM", "TN", "TO", "TR", "TT", "TV", "TW", "TZ", "UA", "UG", "UM", "US", "UY", "UZ", "VA", "VC", "VE", "VG", "VI", "VN", "VU", "WF", "WS", "YE", "YT", "YU", "ZA", "ZM", "ZW"] 
2.2.3 :005 > puts FROZEN_ARRAY.size
252
 => nil 
2.2.3 :006 > FROZEN_ARRAY_AND_STRINGS = country_list.dup.map{|x| x.freeze}.freeze
 => ["AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AI", "AL", "AM", "AN", "AO", "AQ", "AR", "AS", "AT", "AU", "AW", "AX", "AZ", "BA", "BB", "BD", "BE", "BF", "BG", "BH", "BI", "BJ", "BL", "BM", "BN", "BO", "BQ", "BR", "BS", "BT", "BV", "BW", "BY", "BZ", "CA", "CC", "CD", "CF", "CG", "CH", "CI", "CK", "CL", "CM", "CN", "CO", "CR", "CS", "CU", "CV", "CW", "CX", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DJ", "DK", "DM", "DO", "DZ", "EC", "EE", "EG", "EH", "ER", "ES", "ET", "FI", "FJ", "FK", "FM", "FO", "FR", "GA", "GB", "GD", "GE", "GF", "GG", "GH", "GI", "GL", "GM", "GN", "GP", "GQ", "GR", "GS", "GT", "GU", "GW", "GY", "HK", "HM", "HN", "HR", "HT", "HU", "ID", "IE", "IL", "IM", "IN", "IO", "IQ", "IR", "IS", "IT", "JE", "JM", "JO", "JP", "KE", "KG", "KH", "KI", "KM", "KN", "KP", "KR", "KW", "KY", "KZ", "LA", "LB", "LC", "LI", "LK", "LR", "LS", "LT", "LU", "LV", "LY", "MA", "MC", "MD", "ME", "MF", "MG", "MH", "MK", "ML", "MM", "MN", "MO", "MP", "MQ", "MR", "MS", "MT", "MU", "MV", "MW", "MX", "MY", "MZ", "NA", "NC", "NE", "NF", "NG", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NP", "NR", "NU", "NZ", "OM", "PA", "PE", "PF", "PG", "PH", "PK", "PL", "PM", "PN", "PR", "PS", "PT", "PW", "PY", "QA", "RE", "RO", "RS", "RU", "RW", "SA", "SB", "SC", "SD", "SE", "SG", "SH", "SI", "SJ", "SK", "SL", "SM", "SN", "SO", "SR", "SS", "ST", "SV", "SX", "SY", "SZ", "TC", "TD", "TF", "TG", "TH", "TJ", "TK", "TL", "TM", "TN", "TO", "TR", "TT", "TV", "TW", "TZ", "UA", "UG", "UM", "US", "UY", "UZ", "VA", "VC", "VE", "VG", "VI", "VN", "VU", "WF", "WS", "YE", "YT", "YU", "ZA", "ZM", "ZW"] 
2.2.3 :007 > FROZEN_ARRAY_AND_SYMBOLS = country_list.dup.map{|x| x.to_sym}.freeze
 => [:AD, :AE, :AF, :AG, :AI, :AL, :AM, :AN, :AO, :AQ, :AR, :AS, :AT, :AU, :AW, :AX, :AZ, :BA, :BB, :BD, :BE, :BF, :BG, :BH, :BI, :BJ, :BL, :BM, :BN, :BO, :BQ, :BR, :BS, :BT, :BV, :BW, :BY, :BZ, :CA, :CC, :CD, :CF, :CG, :CH, :CI, :CK, :CL, :CM, :CN, :CO, :CR, :CS, :CU, :CV, :CW, :CX, :CY, :CZ, :DE, :DJ, :DK, :DM, :DO, :DZ, :EC, :EE, :EG, :EH, :ER, :ES, :ET, :FI, :FJ, :FK, :FM, :FO, :FR, :GA, :GB, :GD, :GE, :GF, :GG, :GH, :GI, :GL, :GM, :GN, :GP, :GQ, :GR, :GS, :GT, :GU, :GW, :GY, :HK, :HM, :HN, :HR, :HT, :HU, :ID, :IE, :IL, :IM, :IN, :IO, :IQ, :IR, :IS, :IT, :JE, :JM, :JO, :JP, :KE, :KG, :KH, :KI, :KM, :KN, :KP, :KR, :KW, :KY, :KZ, :LA, :LB, :LC, :LI, :LK, :LR, :LS, :LT, :LU, :LV, :LY, :MA, :MC, :MD, :ME, :MF, :MG, :MH, :MK, :ML, :MM, :MN, :MO, :MP, :MQ, :MR, :MS, :MT, :MU, :MV, :MW, :MX, :MY, :MZ, :NA, :NC, :NE, :NF, :NG, :NI, :NL, :NO, :NP, :NR, :NU, :NZ, :OM, :PA, :PE, :PF, :PG, :PH, :PK, :PL, :PM, :PN, :PR, :PS, :PT, :PW, :PY, :QA, :RE, :RO, :RS, :RU, :RW, :SA, :SB, :SC, :SD, :SE, :SG, :SH, :SI, :SJ, :SK, :SL, :SM, :SN, :SO, :SR, :SS, :ST, :SV, :SX, :SY, :SZ, :TC, :TD, :TF, :TG, :TH, :TJ, :TK, :TL, :TM, :TN, :TO, :TR, :TT, :TV, :TW, :TZ, :UA, :UG, :UM, :US, :UY, :UZ, :VA, :VC, :VE, :VG, :VI, :VN, :VU, :WF, :WS, :YE, :YT, :YU, :ZA, :ZM, :ZW] 
2.2.3 :008 > comp_s                   = %w(AD AT BE CY EE FI FR DE ES GR IE IT LU LV MC ME MT NL PT SI SK SM VA)
 => ["AD", "AT", "BE", "CY", "EE", "FI", "FR", "DE", "ES", "GR", "IE", "IT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "ME", "MT", "NL", "PT", "SI", "SK", "SM", "VA"] 
2.2.3 :009 > comp_sym                 = %w(AD AT BE CY EE FI FR DE ES GR IE IT LU LV MC ME MT NL PT SI SK SM VA).map{|x| x.to_sym}
 => [:AD, :AT, :BE, :CY, :EE, :FI, :FR, :DE, :ES, :GR, :IE, :IT, :LU, :LV, :MC, :ME, :MT, :NL, :PT, :SI, :SK, :SM, :VA] 
2.2.3 :010 > 
2.2.3 :011 >   
2.2.3 :012 >   Benchmark.bm do |x|
2.2.3 :013 >       x.report("frozen string"  )  { 10000.times {|i| c = (FROZEN_ARRAY_AND_STRINGS & comp_s.dup) }}
2.2.3 :014?>     x.report("unfrozen string")  { 10000.times {|i| c = (FROZEN_ARRAY             & comp_s.dup) }}
2.2.3 :015?>     x.report("symbols"        )  { 10000.times {|i| c = (FROZEN_ARRAY_AND_SYMBOLS & comp_sym.dup) }}
2.2.3 :016?>   end
       user     system      total        real
frozen string  0.190000   0.000000   0.190000 (  0.194141)
unfrozen string  0.170000   0.010000   0.180000 (  0.174675)
symbols  0.080000   0.000000   0.080000 (  0.081507)
 => [#<Benchmark::Tms:0x007f810c3aca70 @label="frozen string", @real=0.1941408810671419, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.1899999999999995, @total=0.1899999999999995>, #<Benchmark::Tms:0x007f810c82b538 @label="unfrozen string", @real=0.1746752569451928, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.010000000000000009, @utime=0.16999999999999993, @total=0.17999999999999994>, #<Benchmark::Tms:0x007f810af2cfa0 @label="symbols", @real=0.08150708093307912, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.08000000000000007, @total=0.08000000000000007>] 
2.2.3 :017 > 
2.2.3 :018 >   
2.2.3 :019 >   Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
2.2.3 :020 >       x.report("frozen string"  )  { 10000.times {|i| c = (FROZEN_ARRAY_AND_STRINGS & comp_s.dup) }}
2.2.3 :021?>     x.report("unfrozen string")  { 10000.times {|i| c = (FROZEN_ARRAY             & comp_s.dup) }}
2.2.3 :022?>     x.report("symbols"        )  { 10000.times {|i| c = (FROZEN_ARRAY_AND_SYMBOLS & comp_sym.dup) }}
2.2.3 :023?>   end
Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------------
frozen string     0.180000   0.000000   0.180000 (  0.183846)
unfrozen string   0.200000   0.000000   0.200000 (  0.196311)
symbols           0.080000   0.000000   0.080000 (  0.082794)
------------------------------------------ total: 0.460000sec

                      user     system      total        real
frozen string     0.160000   0.000000   0.160000 (  0.167051)
unfrozen string   0.170000   0.000000   0.170000 (  0.171601)
symbols           0.080000   0.000000   0.080000 (  0.078746)
 => [#<Benchmark::Tms:0x007f811022a388 @label="frozen string", @real=0.1670510449912399, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.16000000000000014, @total=0.16000000000000014>, #<Benchmark::Tms:0x007f811022a4c8 @label="unfrozen string", @real=0.17160122003406286, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.16999999999999993, @total=0.16999999999999993>, #<Benchmark::Tms:0x007f8108eb1c58 @label="symbols", @real=0.07874645793344826, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.08000000000000007, @total=0.08000000000000007>] 
2.2.3 :024 > 
2.2.3 :025 >   
2.2.3 :026 >
```

Comment: Run benchmark tests on the two versions. http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html

Comment: Freezing the strings ensures that you cannot change them, e.g. `WORLD_COUNTRIES.first.clear` would raise a `RuntimeError`

Comment: @ReggieB Thanks, I'll post results of testing, for any feedback on the validity of the test and interpretation

Comment: @Stefan Yes, and the arrays themselves and the values in them are considered immutable so that's OK. What i'm trying to avoid is any unnecessary cost in allocation of new objects.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with a small number of values, and since the performance benefits of symbols are evident from your testing, just go with symbols.

BTW, you can use `map(&:to_sym)` instead of `map {|x| x.to_sym}`.

Comment: I'm reluctant to do so only because I have so many places in the system where I store arrays of this sort. So users select from lists of country/language codes, and they are persisted in PostgreSQL text arrays. I think I'd have to migrate to using Rails serialisation instead of text arrays (so I'd lose access to the values through SQL as well), and rewrite view and model code. It's too big a solution for something that might not even be a problem.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I agree the gains may not be worth it, but FWIW you don't have to rewrite much of anything. That's one area where Ruby's support for monkey patching really shines.

Comment: @ChrisJesterYoung I can see that I could be overwriting getter and setters to be converting arrays of strings to/from arrays of symbols, so I store as array of string but use as array-of-symbol, but my concern is really the amount of memory and GC being required by continually using these arrays. If the quick fix is to freeze the strings in the arrays then that's very do-able, but at the moment I'm having trouble quantifying the difference in memory usage even.

Comment: @DavidAldridge The strings aren't being copied or anything, whether or not you freeze them. If you're really trying to minimise memory usage, you don't have anything to do.